# When to use an object to call a method?

Tags: java, oop, object, methods

I am confused on when to use an object to call a method. For instance, sometimes I have to do `object.someMethod()` and other times the method works when it is just called `someMethod()`. If anyone could clarify when I need to use an object and when I do not, that would be great!

Comment: `someMethod()` only works if the method *belongs to the same class* as the method from which you call `someMethod()`. Or if the method is `static`-imported.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling non-static class members, you always need to specify the instance. However, there is one short-cut if you are inside a member function: Instead of writing `this.otherMethod()`, you can omit the `this.` part and only write `otherMethod()`, as it will be implicitly assumed by the compiler. It is a common situation and readability is not hurt from omitting it:

```
class Foo {
  public void someMethod() {
    otherMethod(); // same as calling: this.otherMethod()
  }

  public void otherMethod() {
  }
}

MyClass object = new MyClass();
object.someMethod();

MyClass object2 = new MyClass();
someMethod(); // ERROR: from the context, it is not clear which instance is meant:
              // Do you mean object.someMethod() or object2.someMethod()?
```

Note that it only works for methods of the same class. If you call it from outside, it will be a compile error. In the example above, it is mandatory that you explicitly write `object.someMethod()` or `object2.someMethod()`.